# Keystore file 'C:\chavedeapp\upload-keysore.jks' not found for signing config 'release' - flutter build appbundle

Tags: flutter, bundle

I took a look here on the page, but I didn't find the solution to the following problem:

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

based on the image, u seem to expect that an `upload-keystore.jks` should be found in that directory, but **it's not**.
you put the `upload-keystore.jks` file in the wrong directory, or the path you set to find it is not where it is

**quick solution:**

- Search for the file where you put it.
- Copy/cut it.
- Go to the `c:\chavedeapp` directory
- paste it there
- run again the build command

It will find it this time on that path if it exists there

Comment: if this helps you, I will appreciate it if you upvote the answer so other people having this problem finds it's solution quickly.